# Tibco buildear error - generate ear file on cmd

Tags: null, runtime-error, archive, ear, tibco

I am trying to generate an .ear file on the command line. I get the following error:

```
Starting up...
The resource path to the ear 'null' doesn't begin with a '/'
Aborting.
```

When I run this command, I am in the folder where my where the archive is. I am using the following command:

```
buildear.exe -s -ear "CustomerDetailsService.archive" -o "C:\repos\sc\Projects\CustomerDetails\Deployment\Services.ear" -p "C:\repos\sc\Projects\CustomerDetails"
```

I realise the error is telling me the .archive file doesn't start with a '/', but, I'm not sure how I can set the file to begin with a '/'. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the space in the path. Give this a try:

```
buildear -s -ear /CreditCheck.archive -o "C:\Tibco direct\CreditCheck\EarFile\CreditCheck.ear" -p "C:\Tibco direct\CreditCheck"
```

Comment: Probavly you have chexk

Comment: Please try as shown following
buildear.exe -s -ear /CustomerDetailsService.archive -o "C:\repos\sc\Projects\CustomerDetails\Deployment\Services.ear" -p "C:\repos\sc\Projects\CustomerDetai

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. Get the following: `If you don't specify an '-ear' argument, the tool will create a
full project ear packaging all adapters in their own Adapter Archives,
and all process definitions in a single Process Archive. Note this
feature is not implemented for packaging other types of Archives. If your
project resources that need to be packaged in their own archives, you
will need to build the EAR resource in Designer, and then use this tool
to create the ear file

Aliases file format is:
NameOfTheAlias=/path/to/the/library`